# Segmentation fault - C language - Struct and For loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when i am running the below:
The printf is only for testing the result, as i want to get this info and add it in another array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct proion
{
    char onoma[30];
    float timi;
    int stock;  
};

int main()
{   
int i;
    for (i=0;i<=200;i++)
    {
        struct proion proion[i];
        strcpy (proion[i].onoma,"test");
        proion[i].timi=5;
        proion[i].stock=10;

        printf("%s\n%.2f\n%d\n",proion[i].onoma, proion[i].timi,proion[i].stock);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what is the code supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

allocate memory In the for loop you are creating an array for Proion. 
First loop is:

```
struct proion proion[0];
```

So when you access `proion[i]` you get a segmentation fault since there is no memory allocated for that variable.

This will be also true for other loops because you are access the ith element of the array but you only have `0 to i-1` elements.

The approach is however wrong. Seems like you are trying to create 200 structs. In that case just create the array outside the loop or use `malloc` to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: this is the actual cause for the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

You likely mean to say:

```
struct proion proion[200];

for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    strcpy(proion[i].onoma, "test");
```

Currently, you're creating a new array each time, e.g. when `i == 5`, it's like you're saying:

```
struct proion proion[5];
strcpy (proion[5].onoma,"test");
```

which will write to the struct just past the end of the array (causing the segmentation fault). And, of course, the whole array is thrown away after every loop.

Also note, in the corrected version, we say `i < 200`, not `i <= 200`, if we're working with an array of size 200.

Comment: I am really curious about what is `struct proion proion[i];
` doing inside the loop?

Comment: Almost certainly a mistake, which is why I suggest it belongs outside.

Comment: I want to create 200 structs of format "proion" which has 3 values:
1.onoma
2.timi
3.stock

i will create another array of 200 records, so that the newly created structs get the info from around some arrays.

Comment: "which will write to the struct just past the end of the array. And, of course, the whole array is thrown away after every loop."

How can i save these structs for future queries? like, which was the highest one in one of the details?

Comment: In the corrected version, all of those structs are in the array. They were only thrown away in the original version, where 201 arrays were created and destroyed during the for loop.